# How to replace a character once in a text in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe "X_test" that contains an index and one text column "review". I want to check the text and replace character 'b' with '6' just one time: if the text contains the 'b' character several times I want the replacement to be done only once randomly.

The code below replaces b in all places in line 2 for example:

```
X_test["modified_review"] = X_test["review"]
X_test.loc[2, "modified_review"]= X_test.loc[2, "modified_review"].replace('b','6')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a custom function.

Let's split the string, and join it back with one item being replaced randomly:

```
import random

def random_sub(s, pat, repl):
    # split the string on target character
    l = s.split(pat)
    # create a list with the size of the separators
    # e.g.  AxAxAxA -> 4 chunks, 3 separators
    # [A, A, A, A] and [x, x, y]
    # with original separator except 1
    new = [pat]*(len(l)-2)+[repl]
    # shuffle randomly
    random.shuffle(new)
    # join back with the interleaved separators
    return ''.join([e for x in zip(l, new+[None]) for e in x][:-1])

Xtest.loc[2, 'modified_review'] = random_sub(Xtest.loc[2, 'modified_review'], pat='b', repl='6')

print(Xtest)
```

Output:

```
  modified_review
0            aaaa
1             cbc
2        aba6abab
```

Comment: @jezrael I missed that, then a custom function is needed

Comment: @mozway when I use str I get the error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' and when I use only n=1 I get the error TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @SLA are you using my previous code before edit? I'm not using `replace` in the current version. Make sure to refresh the page.

Comment: yes I just saw the new version but I'm not sure to understand everything. if you can add some explanation, please

Comment: @SLA sure, I commented the code, you might want to try it step by step on a single string ;)

Answer (score 0):

If speed isn't relevant, you can write a function that does the replacement for a single string and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it to the column.

This function randomly selects an index of a matching character and replaces that position in the output (i.e., it's only going to work for single characters – for longer patterns see mozway's answer or use regular expressions):

```py
import random

def random_replace(string, char, repl):
    if char not in string:
        return string

    string = list(enumerate(string))
    to_replace = random.choice([i for i,c in string if c==char])

    return ''.join(repl if i == to_replace else c for i,c in string)
```

With that in place, you can do `Xtest.loc[2, 'modified_review'] = Xtest.loc[2, 'modified_review'].apply(random_replace, char='b', repl='6')`.

Answer (score 0):

random makes it a bit complicated but we can solve it with a user-defined function.

1. create a df with review column

```
d = {'review': ["black berry", "bibi q", "butter and bread"]}
xtest = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
xtest
```

```
    review
0   black berry
1   bibi q
2   butter and bread
```

2. import random and define the function (I'll explain it below)

```
import random

def replace_random_b(text):
    if 'b' in text:
        b_indexes = [i for i, char in enumerate(text) if char == 'b']
        random_b_index = random.choice(b_indexes)
        text = text[:random_b_index] + '6' + text[random_b_index+1:]
    return text

xtest["modified_review"] = xtest["review"].apply(replace_random_b)
```

Explanation: replace_random_b function will replace the character 'b' in the 'review' column. It first checks if there are any 'b' in text, if yes it converts the text to list and creates a list of index where 'b' is present. Then through random.choice function we'll choose a random index from the list of indexes where there is a 'b' and replace the character at that index with 6. Last we assign the modified text to "modified_review" column by using apply function. Hope it's clear. But since it's a function, you can use it for all similar cases.

3. and the result:

```
xtest["modified_review"]

0         6lack berry
1              bi6i q
2    6utter and bread
Name: modified_review, dtype: object
```